# how to roll back broken privileges in 14.04?

Tags: udev, pam, privileges, policykit, console-kit

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 32bit OS. A few months ago I wanted to install QTCAM from source which 
 it requires systemd library files. 
 As you know 14.04 Ubuntu doesn't use systemd yet, so,  as the author said 
 I compiled and installed systemd218 version of it.
 I set prefix a local path not to mess up system configuration. I compiled and installed it.
 On the next boot it failed to log in to default user session. It failed to gain access to `~/.cache` directory. 
 When I remove it by logging in to text mode then I can log in to default user session.
 After logging in I tried many things to fix it. I did `sudo make uninstall` 
 from systemd218 source folder hoping that it would roll back the changes but nothing happened.

I reinstalled   all pam related packages.
 I ran `sudo pam-auth-update` to fix authorization problems.

I visited many forums and read bug reports. Though my problem stemmed from a known reason, 
 I met many similar symptoms without a common fix.

I found shared libraries installed by systemd218 in systemd218 source directory like

```
find -name  *.so
./.libs/id128.so
./.libs/_journal.so
./.libs/_reader.so
./.libs/libgudev-1.0.so
./.libs/_daemon.so
./.libs/login.so
./.libs/libsystemd.so
./.libs/pam_systemd.so
./.libs/libudev.so
```

and reinstalled  every package contains those from synaptic.

I also located conf files, they are lots.

```
find -name  *.conf
./sysusers.d/basic.conf
./sysusers.d/systemd.conf
./sysusers.d/systemd-remote.conf
./src/timesync/timesyncd.conf
./src/core/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf
./src/core/system.conf
./src/core/user.conf
./src/journal-remote/journal-upload.conf
./src/journal-remote/journal-remote.conf
./src/resolve/org.freedesktop.resolve1.conf
./src/resolve/resolved.conf
./src/locale/org.freedesktop.locale1.conf
./src/login/logind.conf
./src/login/org.freedesktop.login1.conf
./src/hostname/org.freedesktop.hostname1.conf
./src/bootchart/bootchart.conf
./src/udev/udev.conf
./src/journal/coredump.conf
./src/journal/journald.conf
./src/machine/org.freedesktop.machine1.conf
./src/timedate/org.freedesktop.timedate1.conf
./test/bus-policy/hello.conf
./test/bus-policy/methods.conf
./test/bus-policy/test.conf
./test/bus-policy/signals.conf
./test/bus-policy/check-own-rules.conf
./test/bus-policy/ownerships.conf
./test/bus-policy/many-rules.conf
./sysctl.d/50-default.conf
./sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf
./factory/etc/nsswitch.conf
./tmpfiles.d/var.conf
./tmpfiles.d/etc.conf
./tmpfiles.d/x11.conf
./tmpfiles.d/systemd-nologin.conf
./tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
./tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf
./tmpfiles.d/legacy.conf
./tmpfiles.d/systemd-remote.conf
```

**Most important ones must be udev rules. I think one of them broke my system**.

```
find -name  *.rules 
./src/login/71-seat.rules
./src/login/73-seat-late.rules
./src/login/70-uaccess.rules
./src/login/70-power-switch.rules
./src/vconsole/90-vconsole.rules
./rules/60-persistent-serial.rules
./rules/60-persistent-alsa.rules
./rules/80-net-setup-link.rules
./rules/61-accelerometer.rules
./rules/50-udev-default.rules
./rules/60-persistent-input.rules
./rules/80-drivers.rules
./rules/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
./rules/75-probe_mtd.rules
./rules/75-tty-description.rules
./rules/70-mouse.rules
./rules/60-cdrom_id.rules
./rules/95-udev-late.rules
./rules/60-drm.rules
./rules/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
./rules/75-net-description.rules
./rules/99-systemd.rules
./rules/60-persistent-v4l.rules
./rules/60-keyboard.rules
./rules/64-btrfs.rules
./rules/60-persistent-storage.rules
./rules/78-sound-card.rules
```

It has many other symptomps such as:

- Gui applications don't prompt elavated privileges to enter password. 
  For example when I click account type -> change button in `users-admin` window nothing happens ( gksu runs OK)
- Nautilus doesn't mount partitions when I click them on the device list. I get **"Not authorized to perform operation"** error.
- Lightdm background image can not update according to user wallpaper.
- When I click nm-applet info section I get **"No active connections found"** error, though network connects automatically.
- I can not reboot without root privileges which must reboot without `sudo` with following command :

  ```
    dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
  ```

I get

```
      org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.NotPrivileged: Not Authorized error.
```

I like my desktop session, I don't want to reinstall whole system. Though it's uncomfortable to enter root privileges 
 to run some applications, I can live with it if one of the smart guys doesn't find a solution.

EDIT:

```
 dpkg -l | grep 'pol.*kit'
 ii  gir1.2-polkit-1.0                                           0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1                                   i386         GObject introspection data for PolicyKit
 ii  libpolkit-agent-1-0:i386                                    0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1                                   i386         PolicyKit Authentication Agent API
 ii  libpolkit-backend-1-0:i386                                  0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1                                   i386         PolicyKit backend API
 ii  libpolkit-gobject-1-0:i386                                  0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1                                   i386         PolicyKit Authorization API
 ii  libpolkit-qt-1-1                                            0.103.0-1ubuntu1                                         i386         PolicyKit-qt-1 library
 ii  plainbox-secure-policy                                      0.5.3-2                                                  all          policykit policy required to use plainbox (secure version)
 ii  policykit-1                                                 0.105-4ubuntu3.14.04.1                                   i386         framework for managing administrative policies and privileges
 ii  policykit-1-gnome                                           0.105-1ubuntu4                                           i386         GNOME authentication agent for PolicyKit-1
 ii  policykit-desktop-privileges                                0.17                                                     all          run common desktop actions without password
```

EDIT2: As Steeldriver intuitively led me on the right path

```
   /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
```

fails to start:

```
   /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 

   (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:10331): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:111:9: 'shade' is not a valid property name 

   (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:10331): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 10331
```

I use **lightdm display manager** and **gnome-cairo-dock** session.

I tried running `exec gnome-session &` in terminal which gives me more clues.

I got following output :

```
   (gnome-session:23129): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:111:9: 'shade' is not a valid property name 

   (gnome-session-check-accelerated:23133): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: unity.css:111:9: 'shade' is not a valid property name 
   gnome-session[23129]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
```

EDIT:3

I add `/etc/pam.d/*` files. I thought `sudo pam-auth-update --force` would fix the pam configuration but when I modify `umask=0022` to `umask=022` in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` it did not notice the modification, and issued no warning.

```
$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/pam.d/common-auth | sed 's/^/    /' 
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_first_pass
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    sufficient      pam_usb.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional    pam_mount.so 
auth    optional            pam_smbpass.so migrate
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 


$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/pam.d/common-account  | sed 's/^/    /' 
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_winbind.so 
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required            pam_permit.so
account [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=done ignore=ignore user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=bad]    pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000


$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/pam.d/common-session  | sed 's/^/    /' 
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
session requisite           pam_deny.so
session required            pam_permit.so
session optional            pam_umask.so    umask=0022
session required                pam_unix.so try_first_pass  nullok_secure 
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional            pam_winbind.so 
session optional    pam_mount.so 
session [success=ok default=ignore] pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000
session optional    pam_systemd.so 
session optional            pam_ck_connector.so nox11


$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/pam.d/common-password |   sed 's/^/    /' 
password    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_winbind.so use_authtok try_first_pass
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 try_first_pass
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so
password    optional            pam_smbpass.so nullok use_authtok use_first_pass
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Symptoms and proposed solutions are almost identical to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336)

one of the guys there claims that appending

```
 session         required        pam_loginuid.so
 session         required        pam_systemd.so
```

lines to `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` fixes the bug. I tried it but it breaks lightdm, I even could not login with it.

```
$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/pam.d/lightdm |   sed 's/^/    /' 
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

EDIT:4

Today when I saw **udev** and **systemd** updates in package I thought I was blessed thinking that update would fix the problem, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Here are the updated packages:

```
gir1.2-gudev-1.0 (1:204-5ubuntu20.17) to 1:204-5ubuntu20.18
libgudev-1.0-0 (1:204-5ubuntu20.17) to 1:204-5ubuntu20.18
libgudev-1.0-dev (1:204-5ubuntu20.17) to 1:204-5ubuntu20.18
libpam-systemd (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-daemon-dev (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-daemon0 (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-id128-0 (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-id128-dev (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-journal0 (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-login-dev (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libsystemd-login0 (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libudev-dev (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
libudev1 (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
python-systemd (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
systemd-services (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
udev (204-5ubuntu20.17) to 204-5ubuntu20.18
```

So, what might be the problem?

EDIT:5

Today I noticed that after the problem arose when I tried to set more permissive authorship I wrongly messed up the ownership in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` I issued `sudo chown -R 777 /etc/polkit-1` instead of `sudo chmod -R 755 /etc/polkit-1` .  I set it to `sudo chown root:root -R  /etc/polkit-1` today.

By the way I noticed that `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` is not that important. I even removed the package that contains it ( policykit-1-gnome ). I tested if it did any change, nothing changed. Then I removed `consolekit` to see the function of it, when I removed it apt-get reinstalled `policykit-1-gnome`, berevity of `consolekit` has no effect on solving the authentication problem I have too.

I don't know if it's important, here is the `pam-auth-update` list:

```
 │    [*] Unix authentication                                                       
 │    [*] Winbind NT/Active Directory authentication   
 │    [*] Mount volumes for user                                              
 │    [*] LDAP Authentication                                                       
 │    [*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy  
 │    [*] SMB password synchronization                                               
 │    [*] GNOME Keyring Daemon - Login keyring management  
 │    [*] ConsoleKit Session Management                                 
 │    [*] Inheritable Capabilities Management
```

EDIT:6

I am beginning to think that it has nothing to do with my modification to file system. I noticed that **upstart** job is not running. May it be related to **upstart** -> **systemd** transition of init process?

Because

```
 echo $UPSTART_SESSION
```

and

```
 initctl list-sessions
```

returns empty string.

I wonder how my system boots up?

Comment: Hmm... the symptoms you're describing sound like they might be related to `policykit`: maybe installation of systemd removed or disabled some polkit components? What does `dpkg -l | grep 'pol.*kit'` say?

Comment: @steeldriver I updated my question regarding your post. You are a master here, I hope you help me.

Comment: Unfortunately I know next to zero about polkit: the list of packages agrees with what I see on my 14.04 system, so I guess it's not as simple as that. You might want to check whether the polkit daemon is running though e.g. `ps -ef | grep [p]olkit`

Comment: @steeldriver it is running but in root `root      1839     1  0 14:42 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug`

Comment: Do you also see a `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` running under your session?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm sorry I am late at responding, I did not find that process, though I have  `gnome-keyring-daemon -s --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg` in applications startup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34769/discussion-between-steeldriver-and-kenn).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu live media has re-installation function.

Boot a live CD or USB and start the installation.  Select the option to install package updates during the installation.  Eventually you will encounter a question asking if you want to "Reinstall Ubuntu".  Selecting that option will make the installer try to not erase your existing system.